How select the first tab in the top navigation bar in React Native when returning from another menu
function TopTabroup(props){
const { initialRouteName } = props;
return (
  <TopTabsGroup.Navigator   initialRouteName={"Berita Terkini"} >
    <TopTabsGroup.Screen name='Berita Terkini'   component={BeritaTerkini}    /> 
    <TopTabsGroup.Screen name='Terpopuler' component={Terpopuler}/> 
    <TopTabsGroup.Screen name='Rekomendasi' component={Rekomendasi}/> 
 </TopTabsGroup.Navigator>

)
}
function TabGroup (){
return(
<Tab.Navigator       screenOptions={{
headerShown: false,
tabBarActiveTintColor :'red',
tabBarInactiveTintColor :'black',
}} >
<Tab.Screen name='Berita Terkini' component={TopTabroup}
options={{
tabBarLabel: 'BERITA TERKINI',
tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (

),
}}
/>
<Tab.Screen name='Topik' component={Topik}
options={{
tabBarLabel: 'TOPIK',
tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (

),
}}/>
<Tab.Screen name='Indonesiaku' component={Foto}
options={{
tabBarLabel: 'FOTO',
tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (

),
}}/>
<Tab.Screen name='Menu' component={BeritaIndonesia}
options={{
tabBarLabel: 'MENU',
tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (

),
}}/>
</Tab.Navigator>
)
}
export default class Home extends Component {
render() {
return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.Header}>
       <Image style={styles.logo} source={require('../assets/logo.png')} />
       
       </View>
        <TabGroup/>
        </View>
)

}
}

when I run the application and enter another page and return to the home page, the top tab navigation does not return to the first tab, but remains on the tab that was selected...I use react-native not expo


Try to navigate when you get back ( screen gets focus)
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

const TopTabsGroup = ({ initialRouteName }) => {
  const topTabNavigatorRef = useRef(null);

  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      if (topTabNavigatorRef.current) {
        topTabNavigatorRef.current.navigate("Berita Terkini");
      }
    }, [])
  );

  return (
    <TopTabs.Navigator ref={topTabNavigatorRef} initialRouteName={"Berita Terkini"}>
      <TopTabs.Screen name='Berita Terkini' component={BeritaTerkini} />
      <TopTabs.Screen name='Terpopuler' component={Terpopuler} />
      <TopTabs.Screen name='Rekomendasi' component={Rekomendasi} />
    </TopTabs.Navigator>
  );
};


hello thank you for answering but in const
However, in TopTabsGroup there is this code:
TopTabsGroup = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
So what should it be like?
const TopTabsGroup = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const TopTabsGroup = ({ initialRouteName }) => {
const topTabNavigatorRef = useRef(null);
useFocusEffect(
React.useCallback(() => {
if (topTabNavigatorRef.current) {
topTabNavigatorRef.current.navigate("Latest News");
}
}, [])
);
